# SQL loading extra fields from table

Tags: sql, database, joomla, field

I have the following sql:

```
tbl_items  
title extra_fields  
Prod1 [{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"2"}]  
Prod2 [{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"2"},{"id":"4","value":"1"}]  
Prod3 [{"id":"2","value":"2"},{"id":"3","value":"2"},{"id":"4","value":"1"}]  
Prod4 [{"id":"2","value":"2"},{"id":"3","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"1"}]  
Prod5 [{"id":"2","value":"2"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]  
Prod6 [{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]  
Prod7 [{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"1"}]  
Prod8 [{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]
```

Now, I want to select all products that contains the value `{"id":"2","value":"2"};`
I am using `joomla cms`.. 
I tried the following statement:

```
$db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE extra_fields LIKE "%{"id":"2","value":"2"}%"');
$xFields = $db->loadObjectList();
```

But it doesn't work for me, Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have your search string in double quotes:

```
"%{"id":"2","value":"2"}%"
```

I don't know how you would escape it, but it needs to result in :

```
'%{"id":"2","value":"2"}%'
```

The following may work:

```
$query = "
  SELECT * 
    FROM ".$db->nameQuote('tbl_items')."  
    WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('extra_fields')." LIKE ".$db->quote('%{"id":"2","value":"2"}%').";
  ";
$db->setQuery($query);
```